# How to sum of (sum products_price of all products of order) follow order by "group by"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

```
$query = "SELECT sum(o.feeship) feeship_total,
(SELECT SUM(p.products_price) FROM products p 
 left join orders_products op on op.products_id = p.products_id  
 WHERE op.orders_id = o.orders_id) AS cost 
FROM orders o ";
$query .= " GROUP BY year(o.date_purchased), month(o.date_purchased)";
if ($sel_month<>0) 
    $query .= ", dayofmonth(o.date_purchased)";
$query .=  " ORDER BY o.date_purchased";
```

With the above SQL , only `select sum products_price` of all products of first orders . How to sum of (`sum products_price` of all products of order) follow order by `group by`. it look as how to write same sql to select `feeship_total` and `sum(cost)` ?

Comment: SUM(p.products_price) ~~ SUM(p.products_price*op.quantity)

Comment: thanks but you should invisible tag html <br/> and insert line breaks

Comment: please clearify your question and put your data on http://sqlfiddle.com so that we can try

Comment: @raheel-shan , I try in sqlfiddle.com but my brrowser notify "The connection was reset".

Comment: @hvtruong - sorry about that! sqlfiddle is my site, and I had a server issue last night.  It's up and running fine now though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.date_purchased) AS PurchaseYear, SUM(sub.ptotal) AS feeship_total
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN
( 
   SELECT op.order_id, SUM(p.products_price * op.quantity) as ptotal
   FROM products p
   LEFT JOIN order_products op ON p.product_id = op.product_id
   GROUP BY op.order_id
) sub ON o.order_id = sub.order_id
GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_purchased), MONTH(o.date_purchased)
ORDER BY 1;
```

The `INNER JOIN` returns list of orders and the sum of its products' quantities from `order_products` table, each of these products multiply by their corresponding prices from `products` table. The `JOIN` this result set with the orders on the `orderid` column from each result sets. Then you can `GROUP BY` any column you want, in your case if you `GROUP BY` order year.

Comment: but will very slow if I `LEFT JOIN void jp` to `SUM(sub.ptotal - jp.fund + jp.charge)` . how way to optimize ?

Comment: @hvtruong, Can you please edit you question again with the query with `LEFT JOIN void jp` I can't understand how you joined to `SUM(sub.ptotal - jp.fund + jp.charge)`

Comment: it also a problem to optimize .

Comment: ` SELECT YEAR(o.date_purchased) AS PurchaseYear, SUM(sub.ptotal - jp.fund + jp.charge) AS feeship_total
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN orders_total ot ON o.order_id = ot.order_id   LEFT JOIN void jp ON jp.order_id = jp.oid
INNER JOIN
( 
   SELECT op.order_id, SUM(p.products_price * op.quantity) as ptotal
   FROM products p
   LEFT JOIN order_products op ON p.product_id = op.product_id
   GROUP BY op.order_id
) sub ON o.order_id = sub.order_id WHERE ot.class = "total"
GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_purchased), MONTH(o.date_purchased)
ORDER BY 1;`

Comment: @hvtruong, Why do you need `LEFT JOIN` can you please explain what do you want to accomplish with this query? I think you won't need all these `LEFT JOIN`, or you might want to change the order of the JOINs. For example, Why do you need `FROM orders o LEFT JOIN orders_total` even though every order in the orders table should has total in `orders_total` is this what you meant with your query, or is it possible to have orders with no totals in the `orders_total` table and you want to find these orders that has no total in the `orders_total`? this is just for one JOIN.

Comment: `orders_total` for `WHERE ot.class = "total"`  . i can show that query to ` SELECT YEAR(o.date_purchased) AS PurchaseYear, SUM(sub.ptotal - jp.fund + jp.charge) AS feeship_total FROM orders o LEFT JOIN void jp ON jp.order_id = jp.oid INNER JOIN ( SELECT op.order_id, SUM(p.products_price * op.quantity) as ptotal FROM products p LEFT JOIN order_products op ON p.product_id = op.product_id GROUP BY op.order_id ) sub ON o.order_id = sub.order_id GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_purchased), MONTH(o.date_purchased) ORDER BY 1;` but still slow